# passing javascript array to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I've a javascript array and I want to iterate them with jstl for each and display the output.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    phoneFilterObject = {
        allPhoneArray: []
    }
    var specPhone = [];
    OnUserSelect(){
    //loop through allPhoneArray
    //do filtering logic and populate specPhone array
    }
</script>
<body>
    // here I want to iterate through the specPhone array and display it. also I want to  populate hidden variables with values from specPhoneArray
    // i want to do the following
 <c:if test="${!empty specPhoneArray}">
      <c:foreach items="${specPhoneArray}" var="phoneObj">
            <c:out value="${phoneObj.name}"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="phoneID" value="<c:out value='${phoneObj.id}'/>"/>
      </c:foreach>
  </c:if>
</body>
```

i'm not able to read javascript array in jquery. I tried the following

```
specPhoneArray = $(specPhoneArray); &
specPhoneArray = ${specPhoneArray};
this.specPhoneArray = $(specPhoneArray);
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: jQuery can be used intertwined within javascript, it *is* javascript afterall.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Perhaps a jsfiddle is in order?

Comment: JSTL is for Java variables; it has nothing to do with JavaScript at all. If you have access to the variables on the server side, do the work there. If you don't, then you need to build the DOM elements with jQuery. But how are you creating the JavaScript array?

Comment: I've a droplet which gives me a JSONArray of phone, with the JSONArray i'm creating new subsets for each functionality. i'm filtering phone capabilities in one array and I want to display that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with JSTL but you can accomplish it by staying in JavaScript world. First create a template and add it to your page:

```
<script id="phone-tmpl" type="text/html">
  {name}
  <input type="hidden" name="phoneID" value="{id}"/>
</script>
```

then in JavaScript add a little template helper:

```
function t(s,d) {
  for (var p in d) {
    s = s.replace(new RegExp('{'+p+'}','g'), d[p]);
  }
  return s;
}
```

and then you can do (assuming you are using jQuery):

```
var phoneTmpl = $('#phone-tmpl').html(),
    html = "";

for (var i = 0, l = specPhone.length; i < l; i++) {
  html += t(phoneTmpl, specPhone[i]);
}

// do something with html
$('body').append(html);
```

You can also check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d5jaY/

Comment: I personally don't like the idea of having html elements as a string and then appending them to the div/html..

Comment: that's too bad because this is becoming a standard way to handle templates from the client side. All other common js frameworks handle it in a similar fashion...

Comment: Its difficult for someone whos going to debug the code, thats why I don't like the idea of having html elements as string inside javascript. In my case the html element will look like var html="<select id='phoneFeatureSelect' name='phoneFeatureSel' onchange='callFeatureChange()'><option value='feature1'>feature1</value></select>

Comment: @cstephen your template could actually look like: `<option value="{value}">{value}</option>` the <select id="phoneFeatureSelect" name="phoneFeatureSel"> could be a part of the html page. After you generate all selects you could do $('#phoneFeatureSelect').html(html); Also adding onchange='callFeatureChange()' to select is not a good practice. You can read more about Unobtrusive JavaScript here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript